# How many ways can the 60 people from 20 countries be seated so that each president are sitting consecutively?

Tags: combinations

The full question is: How many ways can the 60 people from 20 countries be seated **around a table** so that each president, vice president, and poet laureate are sitting consecutively?

The answer I come up with is : (19!)*6

19! = the number of ways to arrange each country in the table = (20-1)!

6 = the number of ways to arrange the seat of three people in each country which are:

[P,V,L]

[P,L,V]

[V,P,L]

[V,L,P]

[L,V,P]

[L,P,V]

But I'm an not sure if whether or not this answer is correct. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Why did you subtract $1$ from $20$?

Comment: @DreamConspiracy round table, I guess.

Comment: @Brian Cheung that should be made clear in the question though

Comment: @BrianCheung I just notice that so I fixed it. Is $(3!)^(20)$ represented 6 ways we insert the people in the table for 20 countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, each triplet of [P, V, L] as one bundle. So, there are total $20$ bundles.

Now, arranging these $20$ bundles on a circular table requires $(20-1)!$

Also, these bundles can be arranged internally which requires $3!$

Thus, the answer will be $$19! * (3!)^{20}$$

Answer (score 2):

You are nearly correct. Let's look at the steps needed to create a valid arrangement of people:

Step 1: Order the countries. $19!$ orderings (correct).

Step 2: Order the three people from country one. $6$ orderings (correct).

Step 3: Order the three people from country two. $6$ orderings (important).

...

Step 21: Order the three people from country $20$. $6$ orderings (important).

By the product rule we then have a total of $19!6^{20}$ arrangements.